# Define Parent after initializing elements via GraphML

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, graphml

I like to work with components which can be defined via the parent property (https://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/compound-nodes)

However, I do not define my network graph by hand my load a graphml-file via cytoscape.js-graphml:

```
    var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
     ready: function () {
         this.graphml({layoutBy: 'random'});
         this.graphml(graphStr);
     }
    });
```

The graphml file looks like :

```
on='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd"><key attr.name="relationship" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d8"/>

<key attr.name="node_name" attr.type="string" for="node" id="d0"/>
<key attr.name="parent" attr.type="long" for="node" id="d1"/>
<graph edgedefault="directed">
<node id="123">
  <data key="d0">First</data>
  <data key="d1">0</data>
</node>
<node id="124">
  <data key="d0">Second</data>
  <data key="d1">1</data>
</node>
...
```

Where d1 indicates the parent/component id.
The question is, how do I define the parent variable of a node afterward. The graphml is automatically generated and can not be modified.

THX
Lazloo